# What URL does Facebook app use for data?

Tags: facebook, url

I want to block the Facebook app on my iPhone. I've blocked facebook.com in restrictions and every single Facebook URL for servers I can find - this works great in safari, but open the Facebook app and nothing is blocked. What URL do I need to block to fix this?

EDIT: I know school filters somehow are able to do this so there has to be a URL..

Comment: I would imagine there are a large range of URLs used, and they probably vary depending on your connection at any given time (since they use Content Delivery Network[s], and which node you are connected to will depend on where you are and what ISP you are connecting through).

Comment: Why not just delete the app

Comment: Doesn't URL blocking in Restrictions only apply to Safari anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are blocking URL in iOS you only block them for Safari and applications using an in-app browser.

So you won't be able to block Facebook that way.

Comment: Thanks! I do understand now that school systems block the Facebook server IPs, etc at a router level, so no device on that wifi would be able to access it. Makes sense now!